# Как добавить в этот класс удаление ребра из графа?

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, ооп, графы

Есть код:

```
import queue  
from collections import namedtuple

Edge = namedtuple('Edge', ['vertex', 'weight'])


class GraphUndirectedWeighted(object):  
    def __init__(self, vertex_count):
        self.vertex_count = vertex_count
        self.adjacency_list = [[] for _ in range(vertex_count)]

    def add_edge(self, source, dest, weight):
        assert source < self.vertex_count
        assert dest < self.vertex_count
        self.adjacency_list[source].append(Edge(dest, weight))
        self.adjacency_list[dest].append(Edge(source, weight))

    def get_edge(self, vertex):
        for e in self.adjacency_list[vertex]:
            yield e

    def get_vertex(self):
        for v in range(self.vertex_count):
            yield v


def dijkstra(graph, source, dest):  
    q = queue.PriorityQueue()
    parents = []
    distances = []
    start_weight = float("inf")

    for i in graph.get_vertex():
        weight = start_weight
        if source == i:
            weight = 0
        distances.append(weight)
        parents.append(None)

    q.put(([0, source]))

    while not q.empty():
        v_tuple = q.get()
        v = v_tuple[1]

        for e in graph.get_edge(v):
            candidate_distance = distances[v] + e.weight
            if distances[e.vertex] > candidate_distance:
                distances[e.vertex] = candidate_distance
                parents[e.vertex] = v
                if candidate_distance < -1000:
                    raise Exception("Negative cycle detected")
                q.put(([distances[e.vertex], e.vertex]))

    shortest_path = []
    end = dest
    while end is not None:
        shortest_path.append(end)
        end = parents[end]

    shortest_path.reverse()

    return shortest_path, distances[dest]


def main():  
    g = GraphUndirectedWeighted(100)
    g.add_edge(1, 2, 3)
    g.add_edge(1, 3, 8)
    g.add_edge(2, 3, 4)
    g.add_edge(2, 4, 7)
    g.add_edge(3, 4, 1)
    g.add_edge(4, 5, 7)
    shortest_path, distance = dijkstra(g, 1, 4)
    print(distance)

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    main()
```

Как сделать чтобы была еще возможность удалять ребро(по двум заданным вершинам)?
И если не трудно как сделать чтобы выдавался мин путб который состоит менее чем из двух ребер(<=2 ребра)

Comment: путь по 2 рёбрам делается явно не этим алгоритмом. Лучше всего обычным циклом перебрать промежуточную вершину. Удалить ребро сводится к поиску в массиве. Это думаю вы и сами сделаете.